# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with struct

Tags: c, linked-list, exc-bad-access

The following code creates an array of structs from 1~9 as vertices, then it accepts the rest that the vertex points at. For example, if someone enters 1 as a main vertex, he would allow to enter multiple nodes for a graph. However, I'm currently facing an issue with the third while loop and the last. For this part, it should detect that the next is NULL and exit but its giving me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

int main(){
    struct node *G[10];
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        G[i]= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        G[i]->data = i;
        G[i]->next = NULL;
        printf("%i\n", G[i]->data);
    }
    int input = 10;
    int vertixBeingModi=1;
    printf("Please enter your vertix you want to modify? \n");
    scanf("%i", &vertixBeingModi);
    while(vertixBeingModi != 0){
        while (input != 0){
            printf("Please enter the edges ? \n");
            scanf("%i", &input);
            struct node* cursor;
            struct node* newItem;
            cursor = G[vertixBeingModi];
            if (input == 0){
                break;
            }
            while(cursor->next != NULL )
            {
                cursor = cursor->next;
            }
            newItem = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            cursor->next = newItem;
            newItem->data = input;
            cursor = G[vertixBeingModi];
        }
        printf("Please enter your vertix you want to modify? \n");
        scanf("%i", &vertixBeingModi);
        input = 1;
        if (vertixBeingModi == 0){
            break;
        }
    }
    int array[10];
    struct node* tempDegree;
    int counter = 0;
    for(int x = 1; x < 10; x++){
        tempDegree = G[x];
        if(tempDegree->next == NULL){
            continue;
        }else{
            while(tempDegree->next != NULL ){
                counter = counter + 1;
                tempDegree = tempDegree->next;
            }
            array[x] = counter;
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", array[1]);
}
```

Comment: I recommend that you [learn how to debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). More specifically, learn how to use a debugger to catch the crash as and when it happens, and locate where in your code it happens.

Comment: on a completely different note `for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)` index with 0

Comment: Also think about the order you do some things. For example `cursor->next != NULL && cursor != NULL` will fail and lead to you dereferencing `cursor` if `cursor` is a null pointer.

Comment: Your code looks terribly convoluted. What is the program supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot to initialize `newItem->next`:

```
while (cursor->next != NULL)
  {
    cursor = cursor->next;
  }
  newItem = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  newItem->next = NULL;    // <<<<<<<<<<<< add this line
  cursor->next = newItem;
  newItem->data = input;
  cursor = G[vertixBeingModi];
```

Comment: Thank you! it works! but why do we need to add the line? should newitem->next be NULL when i allocate memory for it? trying to understand.

Comment: @NeverSleepAlwaysCode The memory allocated by  `malloc` is not initialized. BTW in your `for` loop at the beginning you initialize the `next` pointer correctly.

Comment: @NeverSleepAlwaysCode No. `malloc` returns a block of memory, but it's contents are indeterminate. If you want to allocate and initialize the new memory zero, then use `calloc`. (And, learn to check the **return** of `scanf` *always*...)